# Azure Powershell programmatic login

Tags: powershell, azure

I am working with Azure (HDInsight in particular) using a personal account (no work/school acocunt).

I would create a script that automatically login on azure and perform some actions.

I found a solutions saving an azure publishsetting json file after logging with our credentials but this settings file contains token that expires.

How can I deal with this issue? What is the best way to accomplish this automatico logon?

Thanks
Roberto

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a service principal.  Once you've created the service principal you can assign it permissions on specific resources using [Role-Based Access Control](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/).  From there your script can login as the service principal without requiring you to login interactively.

The main concern with this approach is securing access to your script since it contains credentials that allow access to your Azure resources.

This [article](https://blogs.endjin.com/2016/01/azure-resource-manager-authentication-from-a-powershell-script/) has a good walkthrough:

```
#First, login as yourself so you can setup the service principal
Login-AzureRmAccount

#Password doesn't have to be *your* password, but the password the script will use
$app = New-AzureRmADApplication –DisplayName "<Your script name>" –HomePage "http://localhost" –IdentifierUris "http://localhost/YourAppName" –Password "<Password>"

#Create the service principal
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal –ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId

#Assign the Reader role to your new service principal.  Other roles listed at
#https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-built-in-roles/
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment –RoleDefinitionName Reader –ServicePrincipalName $app.ApplicationId

$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "<Password>" -AsPlainText –Force

#Servce principal username looks like 92c22f1f-d1d4-46a1-b025-edb47fc03809@something.onmicrosoft.com
#the GUID part is $app.ApplicationId and the domain part is found in the Azure portal
$cred = New-Object -TypeName pscredential –ArgumentList "<Service Principal UserName>", $pass

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred -ServicePrincipal –TenantId <TenantId>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a production/shared setup and more a developer setup you can also do, careful, the password is plain text here:

```
$SubscriptionName = 'MySubscription'
$pswd  = 'MyPassword' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Credential -UserName 'MyEmail@something.com' -Password $pswd
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $creds
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $creds -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of commands that you can fire up to get started.

```
$credentials = Get-Credential

Login-AzureRmAcoount -Credential $credentials

$SubscriptionName
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "The name of your subscription"
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName
```

Answer (score 0):

Below information might help you

- Create an Automation Account in Azure
- Add your credentials in Automation Account as a variable ( e.g 
  `variablename = loginazure`) Below Script will automatically login into azure (use Powershell workflow runbook).

  ```
  $AzureLogin = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'loginazure'  
  $AzurePortalLogin = New-Object -TypeName   System.Management.Automation.PSCredential$AzureLogin  
  Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $AzurePortalLogin   
  Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "your subscription name" | Set-AzureRmContext
  ```

use the above script within `Inline Script {}`

Regards

Thamarai Selvan S